# LDAP user's NFS files are mapped to nogroup (user ID mapped correctly)

Tags: ldap, nfs, ubuntu-14.04

In my office environment, I have set up multiple Ubuntu machines with LDAP authentication using the LDAP & NFSv4 server `hostS`. The LDAP/NFS server `hostS` exports the `/home` directory for all users in the system. A client machine, `hostC`, on which I login using an ldap user `sonny` maps my UID correctly, but not my GID. I tested this by creating a file in `/tmp/` on the machine `hostC`, and it is created with the right GID.

In other words:

```
sonny@hostC:~ $ ls -li .bashrc
4875596 -rw-r--r-- 1 sonny nogroup 5884 Mar 26 10:52 .bashrc
sonny@hostC:~ $
```

But:

```
sonny@hostC:~ $ cd /tmp/
sonny@hostC:/tmp $ touch something
sonny@hostC:/tmp $ ls -li something 
6162694 -rw-r--r-- 1 sonny users 0 Sep  6 09:16 something
sonny@hostC:/tmp $
```

I am using NFSv4, and have configured `/etc/idmap.conf` like so:

```
[General]

Verbosity = 0
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
# set your own domain here, if id differs from FQDN minus hostname
# Domain = localdomain
Domain = sillydomain
[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup

[Translation]

Method = nsswitch
```

And I `/etc/default/nfs-common` (the same in `hostS`):

```
NEED_STATD=
STATDOPTS=
NEED_IDMAPD=yes
NEED_GSSD=yes
```

And yes, when I do `id sonny` on both `hostS` and `hostC`:

```
uid=1001(sonny) gid=1001(users) groups=1000(admin),1001(users)
```

My `hostC` `/etc/fstab`:

```
hostS:/home/        /home/      nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,nfsvers=4 0 0
```

Can anyone tell me why my files are not being created as `sonny users` (i.e., not mapped to my GID as well) on the NFS shares?